# How can I get an enum from an interface to a class that implements that interface?

Tags: java, interface, enums

I am trying to get an enum from this interface:

```
public interface PizzaInterface {
    public enum Toppings {
        pepperoni, sausage, mushrooms, onions, greenPeppers;
    }
}
```

to this class:

```
public class Pizza implements PizzaInterface{
    private String[] toppings = new String[5];
}
```

and be able to store it in the array.

(edit):
I want to put it in a ArrayList if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that Enum will be static inside that Interface. And call to `values()` method on any enum will return the array of enums instances. So if you can work with Enum array rather than String, you should be using that `values()` call like the way pbabcdefp mentioned above. :

`PizzaInterface.Toppings[] toppings = PizzaInterface.Toppings.values();`

But if you need String contents, I would like to suggest you to use ArrayList. There are usually more benefits using ArrayList then to Arrays. In that case , If I were you, I would add one static method inside the Enum class to return the list of strings, which I would have used in the Pizza class. Sample code would be like :

```
public interface PizzaInterface {
public enum Toppings {
    pepperoni, sausage, mushrooms, onions, greenPeppers;

   public static List<String> getList(){
       List<String> toppings=new ArrayList<String>();
       for (Toppings topping:Toppings.values() ){
           toppings.add(topping.name());
       }
       return toppings;
   }
}
```

}

and

```
public class Pizza implements PizzaInterface{
   private static List<String> toppings = PizzaInterface.Toppings.getList();
//use the toppings list as you want
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a `String[]`? A `Toppings[]` would be better. You can do this with

```
PizzaInterface.Toppings[] toppings = PizzaInterface.Toppings.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your values as Strings you can do this:

```
       private String[] toppings = names();

        public static String[] names() {
            Toppings[] toppings = PizzaInterface.Toppings.values();
            String[] names = new String[toppings.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
                names[i] = toppings[i].name();
            }

            return names;
        }
```

otherwise just call the .values() method from your enum and you will get a array of Toppings

```
PizzaInterface..Toppings.values();
```